# alternative keyboards

Tags: keyboard, hardware-recommendation

I use the latest wireless keyboard for my iMac at home. Since I use it for programming most of the time, the little laptop style arrow keys are inadequate. Are there any GOOD alternative apple keyboards available?

EDIT:

Sorry Dori, I should have been more clear. I would specifically like a keyboard which is made for Apple, with the appropriate "command" and extra keys (like F13 - F15, and the volume keys).

Comment: The wired apple keyboard has normal arrow keys is that OK or do you need a wireless keyboard?

Comment: Preferably wireless, but you are right, the normal keyboard (full sized) is pretty good (I'm actually typing on one right now ... I use it at work for windows programming, yuck).

Answer (score 2):

Virtually all USB and Bluetooth keyboards work just fine with Macs.

There are about a [zillion Mac-compatible keyboards](http://www.macworld.com/browse.html?type=3&tag=keyboards), and just because one person loves a given model doesn't mean it will suit another (I still use my [Apple Extended Keyboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Extended_Keyboard), for instance). Some of the bigger makers in the field are [Kensington](http://us.kensington.com), [Logitech](http://www.logitech.com), [Macally](http://www.macally.com), [Matias](http://www.matias.ca)<sup>1</sup>, and [Adesso](http://www.adesso.com).

What in particular (besides bigger arrow keys) matters to you? What do you hate? What do you love? Do you want wireless, or is USB ok?

You might want to check out these two *Macworld* articles:

- [Review Roundup: Keyboards and mice](http://www.macworld.com/article/136399/kbstarter.html?loomia_ow=t0%3as0%3aa38%3ag26%3ar11%3ac0.108741%3ab28975948%3az0)
- [Keyboards buying guide](http://www.macworld.com/article/143905/2009/11/keyboard_buying_guide2009.html)

<sub><sup>1</sup> I bought a Matias keyboard. I hated it. I don't recommend them.</sub>

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I would specifically like an apple specific keyboard.

Comment: While any usb keyboard will _work_, the different meta-key placement is irritating.