# there used to be a full sized wireless keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, hardware

I am a programmer and find the small wireless keyboard hard to use (the small arrow keys and lack of home/end keys). From what I remember there used to be a full sized wireless keyboard, is this correct?

Comment: Remember, you aren't limited to keyboards made by Apple—there are plenty of Mac-compatible wireless keyboards by other vendors. Yes, I remember you wanted [an Apple-specific keyboard](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2665/alternative-keyboards/2666#2666), but other vendors make those, too. For instance, [ *Macworld* raved about](http://www.macworld.com/reviews/product/405188/review/logitech_dinovo_keyboard_mac_edition.html) their love for the [Logitech diNovo Mac Edition Keyboard](http://www.amazon.com/dp/ASIN/B001M4N956).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can even still purchase it from vendors listed on this [Google Shopping page](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?hl=en&expIds=17259,27757,28019&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=full+sized+wireless+keyboard+apple&cp=34&qe=ZnVsbCBzaXplZCB3aXJlbGVzcyBrZXlib2FyZCBhcHBsZQ&qesig=2YVGsA3NYLB8mfMRS1h_yA&pkc=AFgZ2tlglaFoXuKwLFH-pS9Gs0_REv-AgP_ag-hhDqK6RvXOgL4faRTEdjjQ_L3gAMgNlby1PtVlAW-DbWXi51rClXSjZAsozw&qscrl=1&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=15965612330655281358&ei=Og8dTa6nF9P_ngepts2kDg&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=7&sqi=2&ved=0CEsQ8wIwBg#). Unfortunately, that option will run you $120 plus whatever shipping they charge.

An alternative is purchasing it used off eBay, but I only found [one listing](http://cgi.ebay.com/Apple-WIRELESS-KEYBOARD-FULL-SIZE-/110629732180?pt=PCA_Mice_Trackballs&hash=item19c20bbf54#ht_500wt_1156) for the full sized wireless Apple keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you're right, but it is not in the style of the present day designs (flat aluminium enclosure, laptop style keys). It was of the older, chunkier keys present on older Apple desktop keyboards. It was discontinued in about 2007 when Apple redesigned it and released the present day design.

[Details of older design](http://reviews.cnet.com/keyboards/apple-wireless-keyboard/1707-3134_7-30568482)