# Shiny new Macbook Pro -- can oils and sweat damage the screen?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, screen

I have a brand-new Macbook Pro. As I'm almost certainly going to [eventually spill something into the keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5932/do-macally-keyboards-require-drivers-to-function), I picked up a [keyboard skin](http://www.iskin.com/protouch_macbook/). It only took me a few hours to get used to typing with it; skins have come a long way since [the last time I had one on a Mac](http://lowendmac.com/ii/macintosh-iicx.html).

I'm noticing that there's now a faint residue left on the screen, possibly the sweat or oils from my fingertips and palms. (I notice that I lean on the edge of the skin as I type.)

Is this anything that could eventually cause screen damage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screen is glass, so it's highly unlikely that sweat can damage it.

Comment: I hadn't appreciated that the LCD panel itself is under a piece of glass! Excellent point.

Answer (score 2):

Although its unlikely that sweat/oil from fingers will do lasting damage to your screen (in the normal lifespan of a laptop), I would only caution on ensuring that when you periodically clean these stains off that you use a very soft cloth (like the black one that came with your new Macbook Pro).

I've seen a lot of monitors that have been scratched through the use of incorrect cleaning cloths or abrasive cleaning solutions.